# Mod rewrite (apache), existing dir

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, directory

I have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/pictures/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+/)?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).jpg$ /pictures/$1/$3.jpg
```

But this rule not working, I think because the picture directory exists. If I change it to:

```
^/images/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+/)?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).jpg$ /pictures/$1/$3.jpg
```

Every thing is OK. How can I write a rule which will work with existing directories?

Answer (score 0):

It should work even for existing dirs. Maybe the pattern is not correct; try this for example:

```
RewriteRule ^pictures/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+/)?([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([0-9]+).jpg$ /pictures/$1/$3.jpg
```

(just removed the '/' at the begining)

Comment: I think that picture dir are alias. it can be problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You hava a htaccess file in Picture directory.
delete it if you can or write the rule in **pictures/.htaccess** file